# Windows 8 metro apps Share Target Issue to save image in disk C#

Tags: c#, windows-8

i have a problem that, I am sharing image through URI in metro app, and my target app shows share image but i want to save that image in localfolder of disk. please help me

here is my share source code

```
void DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
{
    e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = this.dataPackageTitle;
//    e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = this.dataPackageDescription;
    if (this.dataPackageThumbnail != null)
    {
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Thumbnail = this.dataPackageThumbnail;
// Share Image Through URI       
      e.Request.Data.SetUri(imageHolder.BaseUri); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Blob-Sample-0e35889e/sourcecode?fileId=43594&pathId=603010513).  It's in JavaScript, but the technique should be the same.  Basically, you call HttpClient (instead of XHR as in this sample) to get the image, then use Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.createFileAsync to write it out.

Look at this [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664) for how to use HttpClient for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the image from internet through url; but not from local drive.
You can just share images from local to local folder by Bitmap.